# Installation starter pack of laravel 4 show just the home page

Tags: php, laravel-4

hours that i try to figure out to this problem without any result. I download and followed this guide for install this [StarterPack](https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site) of laravel 4. Everything seems went good. When i go to see the application on: `http://localhost/laravel/public`come out the home page correctly but the other link - route doesn't work. Any suggest for figure out this problem?

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Point your virtual host to the public folder, it's not expecting you to already be in `/laravel/public`

Comment: @wesside yes exactly the problem was because i didn't set the virtual hosting thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Point your virtual host to the public folder, this will fix your routes. it's not expecting you to already be in `/laravel/public`